# React Native If Exist in Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, if-statement, firebase-realtime-database, native

My firebase structure:

[image: enter image description re]

Hello, i am trying;
One person opening a announcement with own userid. After another person get in this announcement's inside. If second person wants to send a notification to first person, he uses first person's userid's table in firebase and he put own userid's to first persons userid's table. If first person wants to see, who sends notification to him, he looks to own user id's table and he sees other peoples userids (other people are sended notification to him).. Now one person can send lots of time notification, i want to one person can send just one time for this reason i am trying to control it.

```
if (firebase.database().ref(`/bavuruistek/${userid}`).child(katilan) === null ) {
  firebase.database().ref(`/bavuruistek/${userid}`)
    .push({
      katilan, istek })
    .then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: STUDENT_REQUEST_SUCCESS });
      Actions.pop();
    });
}
if (firebase.database().ref(`/bavuruistek/${userid}`).child(katilan) !== null) {
  console.log(firebase.database().ref(`/bavuruistek/${userid}/${katilan}`));
  Alert.alert(
    'Mesaj',
    'Daha önce başvurunuz yapılmış!',
    [
      { text: 'Tamam', onPress: () => null }
    ]
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  firebase.database().ref(`/basvuruistek/${userid}`).on('value', (snapshot) => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();     
      const notes = snapshot.val();
      Object.keys(notes).forEach(key => { 
        if (notes[key].katilan !== currentUser.uid) {
          this.setState({ click: true });
      } if (notes[key].katilan === currentUser.uid) {
       this.setState({ click: false });
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `` firebase.database().ref(`/bavuruistek/${userid}`).child(katilan) `` inside an if statement, which doesn't work because 1) [`.child()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#child) returns a `Reference` object. Trying something like this may help you achieve the intended outcome:

```
  firebase.database().ref(`/bavuruistek/${userid}`).child(katilan).once('value').then(snapshot => { 
    if (snapshot.val() === null ) {
      firebase.database().ref(`/bavuruistek/${userid}`)
        .update({ 
          katilan, istek
        })
        .then(() => {
          dispatch({ type: STUDENT_REQUEST_SUCCESS });
        Actions.pop();
        });
    } else {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
      Alert.alert(
        'Mesaj',
        'Daha önce başvurunuz yapılmış!',
        [
          { text: 'Tamam', onPress: () => null }
        ]
      );
    }
  }
```

The main difference is that I'm using [`.once`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once), reading the resulting snapshot value, and using that as part of the if statement to check if it is null.

Comment: hello. first of all, thank you very much for your response. I tried but unfortunately it always get inside to if  but i deleted my datas.

Comment: Why did you delete your data?

Comment: for return null

Comment: Okay I see. It looks like the `.push({ katilan, istek })` part inside the if statement needs to be changed to `.update({ katilan, istek })` because `.push` is treating that path as if it is an array containing values, and not an object like how you have it structured.

Comment: hey, this time the problem is it always update it doesn't get in else method.

Comment: Try deleting that database path again in firebase, to make sure it starts out as null before restarting the app

Comment: i tried but it doesnt work.... i am sending my codes again if you want to look...

Comment: If you tried and it still is not working, that means you deleted a different database path compared to what is being checked by that if statement. Try printing out the `userid` variable you're using inside the string - maybe it's value is null/empty, or it's not what you originally thought it was?

Comment: If i wrote firebase.database().ref(`/bavuruistek/${userid}`).once('value') it connecting and if state happening but the problem is, another user can not register new data because it doesnt see null....

Comment: What is the value `userid` of when you add `console.log(userid)`before that if statement? Does it match up with what you expected it to be? Also, I don't understand the problem about another user registering - it doesn't see null where?

Comment: One person opening a announcement with own userid. After another person get in this announcement's inside. If second person wants to send a notification to first person, he uses first person's userid's table in firebase and he put own userid's to first persons userid's table. If first person wants to see, who sends notification to him, he looks to own user id's table and he sees other peoples userids (other people are sended notification to him).. Now one person can send lots of time notification, i want to one person can send just one time for this reason i am trying to control it

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. You should update your question to include some or most of that so other people understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish (in case they don't read the full comments here)